# A property of functorially finite subcategory

Tags: modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra and $\mathcal{T}$ a full subcategory of mod$A$. $\mathcal{T}$ is said to be contravariantly finite in mod$A$ if for every module $M \in mod A$, there is some $X \in \mathcal{T}$ and a morphism $f:X \rightarrow M$ such that for every $X' \in \mathcal{T}$, the sequence $Hom_A(X',X) \overset{f_{\ast}}{\rightarrow} Hom_A(X',M) \rightarrow 0$ is exact. Dually, we can define covariantly finit subcategories. $\mathcal{T}$ is said to be functorially finite in mod$A$ if it is both contravariantly and covariantly finite.

$X \in \mathcal{T}$ is Ext-projective if $Ext_A^1(X,\mathcal{T})=0$. If $\mathcal{T}$ is a torsion class of a torsion pair and functorially finite in mod$A$, then how to get that there are finitely many indecomposable Ext-projective modules in $\mathcal{T}$ up to isomorphism?

Comment: Did you read somewhere that this is true? In a 1981 paper, "*Almost split sequences in subcategories*" Auslander and Smalø raised this as a problem (with the extra condition that $\mathcal{T}$ should be closed under extensions), and proved it is some special cases. But I thought that the general case (even assuming "closed under extensions") was still not known.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard I read it at page 772 of this paper： https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10468-017-9737-5.pdf

Comment: Ah, in that statement there is an extra assumption that $\mathcal{T}$ is the torsion class of a torsion pair.

Comment: @ Jeremy Rickard Sorry. I thought this condition is not used here. I will re-edit this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This essentially follows from the results of

*Auslander, M.; Smalø, Sverre O.*, [**Preprojective modules over Artin algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(80)90113-1), J. Algebra 66, 61-122 (1980). [ZBL0477.16013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0477.16013).

and

*Auslander, M.; Smalø, Sverre O.*, [**Almost split sequences in subcategories**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(81)90214-3), J. Algebra 69, 426-454 (1981). [ZBL0457.16017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0457.16017).

but an explicit statement and proof can be found in

*Smalø, Sverre O.*, [**Torsion theories and tilting modules**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/blms/16.5.518), Bull. Lond. Math. Soc. 16, 518-522 (1984). [ZBL0519.16016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0519.16016).

Concretely, if $\mathcal{T}$ is a functorially finite torsion class and
$$A\stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} T_0\longrightarrow T_1\longrightarrow0$$
is an exact sequence with $\alpha$ a minimal left $\mathcal{T}$-approximation, then the indecomposable Ext-projective modules are the indecomposable summands of $T_0\oplus T_1$.